# Starting an IntentService from an other thread to optimize performances

Tags: android, animation, optimization, android-fragments

My application has a fragment as the content screen and when you click an item on that fragment's list it is replaced with an other fragment. There is an animation slide out left for the fragment that's being removed and an animation slide in right from the new fragment that's being added. I'm using Traceview to see what causes the animation not to be smooth and noticed the startService() method (for an IntentService) is blocking the UI for quite a bit of time.

[image]
Here we can see the startService() method is using almost 8.6% of the CPU time. The method is called on the onCreate() of my fragment. 
My question is : Is there any problem with putting startService() in an other thread?
I would do something like that :

```
new Thread(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        context.startService(i);
    }
}).start();
```

Also, is there any tips to improve the smoothness of a fragment transaction animation?

Comment: i don't think you need to start a service from a thread.

Comment: The difference of performance is huge. The IntentService will still be executed on the UI thread. The only difference is the creation of the service takes place in an other thread.

Comment: i think you misunderstood the purpose of intent service. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: I dont think so. My problem is the overhead caused by startService() which is run in the UI thread, not with the intent handled in a worked thread. I don't think your comment is relevant to the problem.

Comment: I would focus instead on determining why `startService()` is taking 8.6% of your CPU time, as that is not normal. Culprits would including calling it too many times or having very large extras. "The method is called on the onCreate() of my fragment" -- not according to Traceview. You are calling it from `sendToNetworkService()` on your `ServiceExecutor` class.

Comment: Yes, it seems the problem comes from the writeBundle() method. I dont think my bundle is too big just 3 objects with a few properties. I'm gonna take a deeper look at this. Though, is running startService() on an other thread a problem? It seems like a good solution regarding performances. 
Yes, it's called by sendToNetworkService() which is called on onCreate() of the fragment.